# Getting value from database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Trying to get a single value of data from database.
This code works but returns the top `meta_value` of the database with correct `post_id`. In order to get the correct value it I also need `meta_key` column to be equal to _shipping_phone

```
<?php
global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
$order_id = $order->get_id();
$shipping_phone = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM {$table_prefix}postmeta 
    WHERE post_id = {$order_id}
");
?>          
<div class="shipping-phone"><?php echo $shipping_phone; ?></div>
```

My try at this that doesnt work and returns nothing:

```
<?php
global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
$order_id = $order->get_id();
$shipping_phone = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM {$table_prefix}postmeta 
    WHERE post_id = {$order_id}
    AND meta_key = shipping_phone
");
?>              
<div class="shipping-phone"><?php echo $shipping_phone; ?></div>
```

Comment: Try to echo your sql out so that it becomes visually readable to you on the screen. `echo 'SELECT meta_value FROM '.$table_prefix.'postmeta WHERE post_id = '.$order_id`. then look at it and see if the query is what you expect. Try to copy it into a localhost database and see if it returns any errors. I'm not really familiar with your procedure, so I'm afraid I can't help more than simply going through the debugging of it.

Comment: Is `$order_id` a string or int?

Comment: `meta_key = _shipping_phone` should be `meta_key = "_shipping_phone"`

Comment: `_shipping_phone` is a string or column?

Comment: _shipping_phone is a string in a column called meta_key

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by @Laurence Cherone

```
<?php
    global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $shipping_phone = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT meta_value FROM '.$table_prefix.'postmeta WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = "_shipping_phone"', $order_id ) );
?>              
<div class="shipping-phone"><?php echo $shipping_phone; ?></div>
```